# New Facebook SDK for iOS 6 has a crash issue in iOS 5

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5

In iOS 6 New Facebook SDK is Running But Crash on iOS 5

Error is like this,

```
dyld: Library not loaded:/System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the frameworks that are giving you problems to "Optional" instead of "Required" by going to the project file Summary and scrolling down to Linked Frameworks and Libraries.